# Does it take more time to return a "large object" than it does to return None in Python?

Tags: python, return-value

Is there a significant process time difference between **return something vs. None** ?

Here is sample code

*Case 1*

```
def function_1():

    foo = SOME_HUGE_LIST_OR_STRING

    return foo
```

*Case 2*

```
def function_1():

    foo = SOME_HUGE_LIST_OR_STRING

    return None
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why don't you try [the `timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) in order to answer the question for yourself?

Comment: Actually, if you do it right (or is that wrong?), at least with CPython, you might be able to make the `return None` case come out _slower_ from `timeit`. Why? Because when you `return None`, the last reference to the value in `foo` goes away and therefore it gets freed, while `return foo` keeps it alive, to be freed outside of the scope of what's being timed. But that's obviously not a real benefit, it's just an artifact of the benchmark.

Comment: Interesting caveat, @abarnert. I guess this question needs more context: If UKS is only running this function once, or even a million times, they won't care about this tiny difference; if it's running a billion times, then there are a whole bunch of details that could affect its performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in Python are passed or returned by reference ([the long version is here](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)), rather than by value, so `return`-ing any object (including `None`) is essentially equivalent.

Now, **creating** "some huge list or string" in order to return it may take a lot longer than simply referring to the singleton value `None` in order to return it...

EDIT: I believe there may be some special-casing/optimization of `None` in the standard CPython implementation (whence its implementation as a singleton of `NoneType`), but the difference for this usage is likely negligible.

Comment: Wrt the second paragraph: the code in the post evaluates the value assigned to `foo` in both cases, even if not used in the latter.

Comment: Yes, of course. I only mentioned this because it's possible that the OP is confused about the source of some slowness in his/her code, and thinks it's coming from the `return` statement when it's not...

Comment: For the last paragraph: I'm pretty sure CPython just puts a reference to `None` into the `co_consts` and uses a normal `LOAD_CONST` opcode, so the fact that `None` is a special singleton won't matter. The fact that it's a `LOAD_CONST` vs. a `LOAD_FAST` _might_ matter, but unless you're screwing with the local scope in some way (e.g., `exec`), it probably won't.